# How to add text in active document using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am doing an extension for visual studio. I am getting current active document using DTE but I want to know how to insert some text at the cursor position in the current document.Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ActiveDocument.Selection property:

```
(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection).Text = "my new text";
```

Comment: I was getting an error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'EnvDTE._DTE.ActiveDocument.get'".. This solves it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4788418/1605873