# How to paste text at prompt's position with a Visual Studio Add-In?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to develop a Visual Studio 2013 Add-In (now called Extension Package?) that inserts some text at the prompt's position in the currently opened file when it's key shortcut is pressed, but I'm not being able to find any documentation on this.

Does anyone know how to access this?

Thanks

PS: further information on how to access this kind of data would be nice also, since I need to get the selected text for other functions too.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402325/how-to-add-text-in-active-document-using-c-sharp

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying that solution.. I'll post in that question, thanks.