# How to access current code editor from tool window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I am currently trying to create an extension for this using “Visual Studio 2015”.
I want to create a function that inserts the source code that fits into the cursor part of the current code editor when the button of ToolWindow is clicked.
There was a ToolWindow sample in the SDK template.
However, it was completed in ToolWindow, and no way to access the code editor was written.
How can I get / set the current code editor source code from ToolWindow?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402325/how-to-add-text-in-active-document-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Sergey** suggests, we can use the [TextSelection.Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.textselection.text?view=visualstudiosdk-2015) property.

But somehow I failed to get the Selection in this way for VS2015:`DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection`.

For me, In VS2015 I created a new `custom Tool Window` item, added a simple `TextBox` control in the ToolWindow, and then double-click the default `Click me!` button to navigate to `button-Click` method in `ToolWindow1Control.xaml.cs` file, after that I add code like below to get text from textbox and insert it into editor:

```
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization", "CA1300:SpecifyMessageBoxOptions", Justification = "Sample code")]
        [SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.NamingRules", "SA1300:ElementMustBeginWithUpperCaseLetter", Justification = "Default event handler naming pattern")]
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string text = textBox.Text;
            DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
            (dte.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection).Text = text;
        }
```

So for me, I actually use code below to insert the text:

```
        DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
        (dte.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection).Text = "Add your text here.";
```

**In addition:**

To use the code above, you need to add definitions in `ToolWindow1Control.xaml.cs` file:

```
        using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
        using EnvDTE;
```

Hope it makes some help :)